How can I fill this without filling the holes?
I'm trying to convert an image to a 3D object, I wanted to make it solid but I can't figure out how to fill it without filling the holes with it. Any help is appreciated.
This is the geometry I want to look like the image below. But I can't figure out how to fill it right.

This is the image, which I want to recreate in 3D:


Even though this is a common scenario, it would be better if you attach your .blend file: https://blend-exchange.com/

To my knowledge, there is no other way than (for a complex object like this, otherwise you have LoopTools) manually filling the faces by selecting 4 vertices at a time and pressing F to fill

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Try AltF instead of F (if you want to simplify the topology afterwards you can press X > Limited Dissolve):


what the hell, this is a thing? First time I've seen anyone mention this in years of using blender lol

THere's a lot of hidden tools in Blender  ^^

Wow this is exactly what i wanted thank you so much

That's a good one to know! Also, pressing I to inset after doing this would be a good idea in many cases. You will then be able to do things such as extrude and place a Subsurf modifier on without artifacts from bad topology. (As we know, flat surfaces can get away with bad topo, but curvy or around-corners geometry, not so much.)

Me, too!   Alt-F maps to mesh.fill, and F maps to mesh.edge_face_add (or F2, if activated)

I'm not really sure if you are starting with an svg or what but if you are starting with a curve obj you can just go to the Geometry tab and extrude it before converting it to a mesh

You can also give it a solidify modifier tho that sometimes causes issues
If you starting from the mesh already, you can convert it into a curve and change the setting to '2D' with Fill Mode 'Both'. Then either extrude it or turn it into a mesh and give it the solidify modifier


It was a an image that i mapped through a plane and wanted to get a 3d object out of it, so i dont have those options :( Pressing alt f worked wonders for me

Blender can trace an image into a grease pencil by going to the Object->Convert->Trace image to grease pencil. You can then convert it to a curve and convert that curve to a mesh in the same menu. Make sure to merge the overlapping vertices before doing anything else with it tho. After that you can do the Alt+F or convert it into a curve again to fill it and extrude it

First up, a suggestion for a better title, like Duarte mentioned:
Fill geometry with faces, without overlapping holes, to recreate image in 3D
To the question, it should be pretty simple to fill the vertices and edges with faces. But if you will do that on a regular basis however, I would strongly recommend searching for some add on to do that or follow this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BcjPCjxsCZo
Now explaining, it will just be a bit tedious, but tracing the vertices after the pixels of the image was probably too.
When selecting two vertices and pressing F, you create an edge between those two points. Selecting three or more vertices creates a face inside that group. For your problem you will not want to select all vertices, but starting from below just the vertices that don't enclose a hole completely (I will leave example pics down below). Then you continue and select the vertices further up, again stopping before you select all vertices of an hole. Otherwise the hole will get overlapped with faces. For selecting the vertices, I recommend pressing W till you get the circle selection, which is easier for selecting multiple vertices precisely and quickly.
That's maybe what you got:

That's how I think you should do it.
Select just some of the vertices and then press F:


